# How to remove the call of a function in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following problem, when I start my application charge of a function called Ficha(), which makes a an ajax call, that is fine. The problem arises at one point by another ajax call charge html tags that need to call the function Ficha(), the problem is that this load HTML content n times is performed, and when you call the function card already loaded this those executed n times also throwing the "max call stack size exceeded" error.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

/**
 * Mostrar la lista correspondiente
 **/

var buscanombre = $('#buscanombre');
buscanombre.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (buscarNombre.hasClass('active')) {
        resultadoBus.find('ul').empty();
        BuscarNombre();
        resultadoBus.show();

    } else if (buscarServicio.hasClass('active')) {

        resultadoBus.find('ul').empty();
        BuscarServicio();
        resultadoBus.show();

    } else if (buscarUbicacion.hasClass('active')) {

        resultadoBus.find('ul').empty();
        BuscarUbicacion();
        resultadoBus.show();

    }
    _iBpNActivo = 0;
}).keyup(EfectoKeyup);

Ficha();});
```

---

```
function BuscarNombre() {

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: baseUrl + 'site/getfichas',
    success: function (result) {
        listFichasResultados = [];
        var ResultadoBus = resultadoBus.find('ul');
        ResultadoBus.empty();
        var categoria;
        $.each(result, function (index, item) {

            switch (item.categoria) {
                case 'masaje':
                    categoria = '<span class="s-masajes">masajes</span>';
                    break;
                case 'VIP':
                    categoria = '<span class="s-vip">vip</span>';
                    break;
                case 'PREMIUM':
                    categoria = '<span class="s-premium">premium</span>';
                    break;
                case 'GOLD':
                    categoria = '<span class="s-gold">gold</span>';
                    break;
                case 'madura':
                    categoria = '<span class="s-maduras">maduras</span>';
                    break;
                case 'fantasia':
                    categoria = '<span class="s-fantasia">fantasia</span>';
                    break;
                case 'shemale':
                    categoria = '<span class="s-fantasia">shemale</span>';
                    break;
            }

            ResultadoBus.append(
                '<li idFichas="' + item.idFicha + '" data-modal="ficha-full" class="md-trigger" nombrePortada="' + item.nombre + '">' + item.nombre
                + categoria +
                '</li>'
            );

            listFichasResultados.push('<li idFichas="' + item.idFicha + '" data-modal="ficha-full" class="md-trigger" nombrePortada="' + item.nombre + '">' + item.nombre + categoria + '</li>');

        });
        ModalEffects();
        Ficha();
    }
});}
```

Comment: "max call stack size exceeded" usually means that a function is calling itself uncontrolled, directly or indirectly. Errors usually come with some additional information, like where they happen. Can you show us the code of the functions that are multiple times on that stack-trace?

Answer (score 0):

the idea is to make an object to wrap the function to be able to manage whether the function is already running or is it finished and will go again.

also the xhrCount, since you said that you use many ajax calls, and the way to know whether all the calls are finished, you can do this only on the callback so count at the side the ajax calls, and eacc one update its finished in its callback, and when the counter meets 0 you know its done and you free the function.

```
var runOneAtATime = {
   running : false,
   xhrCount : 0,
   freeRunning : function(){
     if (--xhrCount === 0){
        console.log('running'); 
     } else {
        this.running = false; 
     }
   },
   runOneAtATime : function (){
      if (this.running === true){
         console.log('running');
         return;
      }
      this.running = true;
      var self = this; //so you be able to call in in callbacks
      //do work
      //each ajax.complete calls self.freeRunning()
   }
}
```

EDIT:comments

Comment: Very low quality response, please take the time to explain what you are doing